# Dont know how to sort results in autocomplete jquery!

Tags: jquery, sorting, plugins, autocomplete, autosuggest

Aloha! I use autocomplete jquery plugin to suggest input on the page, suggest search on array with string elements. I use this settings for autocomplete:

```
$("#colorsearch").autocomplete(data, {
        matchContains: true,
        autoFill:false});
    });
```

So...when i start input what i`m looking for, for example 'dave' the results are:
'ravedave', 'sadave','dave' (because it have the same order in data array) and so on....i need that first elements of result list have substring ('dave') at the beginning, like this: 'dave' etc...
I used sort function with custom sorting functions. But it work only outside autocomplete. I need do this inside this plugin. Who knows?

Comment: Sort the records before using in autocomplete

Comment: the `data` var  can be sorted with js array sort

Comment: when you sorted data before using autocomplete it`s not the same when you sort inside, for example: var ar = ['voldemort','mortal','immortal'];ar.sort(); i search for 'mort' and it shows me ['immortal','mortal','voldemort'] this order

Answer (score 0):

There is a variable called sortResults injquery complete and it is true by defaults.So you need to set that variable .

```
$('#txtserach').autocomplete({url:"default.aspx", sortResults: false})
```